# Loop runs 2 times, then Array index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, integer, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm making a class that deletes an element at a specific position in an Integer array. It runs perfectly the first 2 times, but then for some reason it decides that the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException should be thrown.

my code:

```
public class Arraydeletion {

    public static int[] delete (int[] a, int delValPos){
        int[] newArray = new int[a.length-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
            if(a[i]!=a[delValPos]){    //<--- ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException points here
                newArray[i] = a[i];
            }
            else if(a[i] == a[delValPos]){
                newArray[i] = a[delValPos+=1];
            }
        }
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `delValPos`, and how long is `a`?

Comment: Are you sure about `newArray[i] = a[delValPos+=1];`?

Comment: The value of delValPos is being incremented in the else statement... what on earth are you trying to achieve here??

Comment: Could you provide your test case when it brakes after 2 times

Comment: @Ian What I did was using delValPos as an index, got so tierd after sitting with this for alot of hours so I tried everything and that did the trick for me. But now Im using an index variable instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never check that `delValPos` is a valid index within the input array `a`. Your method must validate it before doing anything else, and throw an exception if an invalid `delValPos` is supplied.

Working code would look like this :

```
public class Arraydeletion {

    public static int[] delete (int[] a, int delValPos){
        if (delValPos  < 0 || delValPos >= a.length)
            throw new SomeException(); // TODO decide which exception to throw
        int[] newArray = new int[a.length-1];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (i!=delValPos) {
                newArray[index] = a[i];
                index++;
            }
        }
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

This makes the code much simpler. It copies all the elements except `a[delValPos]` to the output array. Note that you can't use the same index `i` for reading elements from the input array and writing elements to the output array, because after you pass the deleted element, each `i`'th element in the input array would be written to the (i-1)'th place in the output array.

Comment: This solved my problem a bit, I some how managed to get a negativ number delValPos but now it stops when I want to take away the last element of the array. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Necrozze What do you mean by "it stops"? What happens when you call `delete(a,a.length-1)`?

Comment: Sorry it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException again, but this time in another Class. My BinarySearch class, wich does not go through an array. When I call  `delete(a,a.length-1)` it runs for 4 times than throws the Exception again, in the BinarySearch class

Comment: @Necrozze I can't comment about code in another Class, which is not included in the question.

Comment: I thought so, well anyway It goes through the array in that class and somehow gets to index ->7 when I only have index -> 6. I think I can figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and i retrieve outOfBoundException only if delValPos == a.length, so you can check this before loop.

However your code is pretty strange, it seems you want to clone an array except for one element in a certain position, if so this will work better:

```
public static int[] delete (int[] a, int delValPos){
    int delValPos = 0;
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int[] newA = new int[a.length - 1];
        if(a.length > delValPos) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < newA.length ; i++) {
                if(delValPos < i && delValPos != 0) {                       
                    newA[i] = a[i];
                }                       
                else
                    newA[i] = a[i + 1];
            }
        }
    return newA;
}
```

Comment: Your code would fail if delValPos<0 (it would arbitrarily remove the first element of the array), and you forgot the return statement.